# Cut Copy Paste jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if it is possible to select the text anywhere on a webpage and then copy it using jQuery or Javascript.In another language how to invoke `CTRL+X`,`CTRL+C` and `CTRL+V` on a selected text using jQuery or Javascript?.Can this be done?However the CUT command will be invoked on the text which is present in a textarea or textbox not on the hypertext of the webpage. Please let me know.

Comment: Some methods of copying text in browsers to clipboard are [listed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript). You can adapt them to your need.

Comment: I dont want to use flash Jimmy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably invoke the buttons, and copying text on a webpage is most certainly possible with access to the DOM, however it seems like what you are trying to do is access the clipboard, and the way to do that consistently is usually with flash.

The [ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) plugin is the one most commonly used, it's easy to integrate and gives you full access ro the clipboard.

For an example have a look at [CSS3Please](http://css3please.com/), I believe they are using the ZeroClipboard plugin.

Comment: Then your limited to some pseudo code that only works in IE, no other browser that I know of will allow access to the clipboard from javascript.

Answer (score 2):

> Can this be done?
>   ...
>   I don't want to use Flash

No, not if you need it to work in all major browsers.